# Failed asserting that 1 matches expected 6

Tags: php, html, object, testing

i get this test, and i need to write code that pass.

But only what i can get is :
"Failed asserting that 1 matches expected 6 " if i return 6 i get " Too few arguments to function on line 18 and exactly 3 expected "

This is test :

```
    public function powerTest()
{
    $calculator = new Calculator();

    $this->assertEquals(6, $calculator->power(1,2,3));
    $this->assertEquals(0, $calculator->power());
}
```

That is my code :

```
    public function power(int $int, int $int1, int $int2)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think what it's saying is that you need to change `return 1;` to be the correct code to calculate the value you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Asserts by definition require the condition to be true; otherwise, they throw an exception. In this case, your first assert is requiring the result of `$calculator->power(1, 2, 3)` to equal 6, which it doesn't. It returns 1.

6 != 1, so it fails.

The second one provides no arguments to the power function `$calculator->power()`. Your power function has 3 arguments, and all are required. Not providing enough arguments will give you a too few arguments error.

You can make arguments optional by specifying a default value.

```
function foo($bar = true)
```